# How to use a Type object to cast an object of type object into the type referenced by the Type object

Tags: c#, types

I am working on an ASP.NET web forms project and I have created a custom event handler.

```
potected void MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   var actualObject = (ActualObject) sender;

   // I don't want to do what is in the line above.  I want to use my EventArgs
   // parameter 'e' which contains a property of type Type to cast the sender
   // object into the underlying type defined in the EventArg property.

   // I want to do something like this ...

   var actuaObject = (typeof(e.TypeProperty)) sender;

   //i.e.  I don't want to explicitly reference the type to which 
   //I'm trying to cast between the parentheses

}
```

Hope the question is not too convoluted.

Comment: Note that whatever the solution you choose, you will not be able to get type safe code here because the compiler cannot determine the type of actualObject at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dynamic` feature with [`TypeConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class

```
TypeConverter converter = new TypeConverter();
dynamic variable = converter.ConvertTo(sender, typeof(e.TypeProperty));
```

Then you can access your properties but you can't use `IntelliSense`, it's a disadvantage.Other than this, it should work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It compiled fine but failed at run-time.  I have recently inherited this application so I will have to make some fundamental changes that will allow this type of code to work or even alleviate the need to do what I'm tring to do in the first place with regard to my question.  Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Convert.ChangeType` method for standard types; however, it will not convert custom types.

```
public static Object ChangeType(
    Object value,
    Type conversionType
)
```

Example:

```
object d = Convert.ChangeType("3.1416", typeof(double));
```

Note that the returned value is of type `object`. Therefore you might still need a cast somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I guess I need to simplify my approach to this problem.  Best regards.